# How to access member function as member variable in python classes?

Tags: python, class

I've got a class:

```
class Foo():
    def bar(name):
        return something
```

and i want to have

```
foo = Foo()
foo.name
```

returning the same as foo.bar('name'). Is it possible?

Comment: Santo, do you consider foo.'3' a working code? If not, then reconsider the question.

Comment: @BasicWolf I wish we __could__ have numerical attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will automatically use `bar` if the attribute doesn't exist:

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self, name):
        return name
    def bar2(self, attr, value):
        print attr, value
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self.bar(attr)
    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        self.bar2(attr, value)
foo = Foo()
print foo.name
foo.name = 'not name'
```

Comment: You beat me to it, have an upvote. But the `try` clause is unneeded: `__getattr__` is only called [when an attribute lookup has not found the attribute in the usual places](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access). You're confusing it with [`__getattribute__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__).

Comment: @lazyr - I always forget that! I'm so used to catching errors when I use `getattr`.

Comment: Tkans. This works fine. Now I'm considering if I can overload assignment operator and do anologiously (foo.name = val will call bar2(name, val)

Comment: @santo - this ain't C++, Python's '=' is not an operator that you can overload.

Comment: Yes, but `__setattr__` / properties / descriptors have the same effect, as I showed.

Answer (score 1):

As you describe it now, `name` only exists in the scope of the function `bar` and thus `Foo` has no direct access to it unless you store it in its scope. The simplest solution would be to make a member field called `name` and set its value in `bar`.

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None

    def bar(self, name):
        self.name = name
        return something
```

Comment: but I don't know the memberfield's names, it should work also with an arbitrary string like self.name123

Answer (score 0):

Declare your class:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self, name):
        return 'something'
```

You can assign the method to an attribute.

```
foo = Foo()
foo.name = foo.bar
```

If you prefer you can do it in constructor.

Comment: He doesn't want `foo.name` to be `foo.bar`, he wants `foo.name` to be `foo.bar('name')`.

Answer (score 0):

Your class should have an attribute to store the name.

Try this out

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Foo:
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = ''

  def bar(self, name):
    self.name = name
    return "name via bar(): %s" % name


f = Foo()
print f.bar("Jackson")
print f.name
```

Comment: That's not a property, it's an attribute. See http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property for what a property is in Python.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected the changes